# Creating a DTS package that uses a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, dts

We're trying to make a DTS package where it'll launch a stored procedure and capture the contents in a flat file. This will have to run every night, and the new file should overwrite the existing file.

This wouldn't normally be a problem, as we just plug in the query and it runs, but this time everything was complicated enough that we chose to approach it with a stored procedure employing temporary tables. How can I go about using this in a DTS package? I tried going the normal route with the Wizard and then plugging in EXEC BlahBlah.dbo... It did not care for that:

The Statement could not be parsed. Additional information: Invalid object name '#DestinyDistHS'. (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0)

Can anyone guide me in the right direction here?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently I'm working the wrong terminology (sorry, new to this and was using the office-speak). We're working with SSIS here.

Comment: Temporary tables generally require annoying workarounds in SSIS, like tricking the validator with empty selects, etc.  It's usually easier to use physical tables.

Comment: Are you using the temp table inside the stored procedure? If so then calling a the stored procedure using an Execute SQL Task should not be giving you this error. Can you give some more details?\

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to simply populate a non-temp table in your SP, call it and select from the non temp table when exporting?

This is only an issue if you have multiple simultaneous calls to the stored procedure. In this case you can't save to a single table.

If you do have multiple simultaneous calls then you might be able to:

1. Create a temp table to hold results
2. Use `INSERT INTO #TempTable EXEC YourProc`
3. `SELECT FROM #TempTable`

You might need to do this in a more forgiving command line tool (like SQLCMD). It's not as fussy about metadata.